# why do i get an exception when trying to make file in cache

Tags: java, android

```
07-08 01:45:41.080: D/dalvikvm(11371): GC_CONCURRENT freed 125K, 8% free 12454K/13511K, paused 17ms+15ms, total 64ms
07-08 01:45:41.570: E/SpannableStringBuilder(11371): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-08 01:45:41.570: E/SpannableStringBuilder(11371): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-08 01:45:51.065: W/System.err(11371): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/hasebou.karim.simplify/cache/Details.txt: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
07-08 01:45:51.065: W/System.err(11371):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
07-08 01:45:51.065: W/System.err(11371):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
07-08 01:45:51.065: W/System.err(11371):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
07-08 01:45:51.065: W/System.err(11371):    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:127)
07-08 01:45:51.065: W/System.err(11371):    at hasebou.karim.simplify.TimedEventsListFragment.saveFiles(TimedEventsListFragment.java:57)
07-08 01:45:51.065: W/System.err(11371):    at hasebou.karim.simplify.TimedEventsListFragment.addToList(TimedEventsListFragment.java:48)
07-08 01:45:51.065: W/System.err(11371):    at hasebou.karim.simplify.Volume.onOptionsItemSelected(Volume.java:104)
07-08 01:45:51.065: W/System.err(11371):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2629)
07-08 01:45:51.070: W/System.err(11371):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1047)
07-08 01:45:51.070: W/System.err(11371):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
07-08 01:45:51.070: W/System.err(11371):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
07-08 01:45:51.070: W/System.err(11371):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
07-08 01:45:51.070: W/System.err(11371):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:586)
07-08 01:45:51.070: W/System.err(11371):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:162)
07-08 01:45:51.070: W/System.err(11371):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4223)
07-08 01:45:51.070: W/System.err(11371):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17275)
07-08 01:45:51.070: W/System.err(11371):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-08 01:45:51.070: W/System.err(11371):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-08 01:45:51.070: W/System.err(11371):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-08 01:45:51.070: W/System.err(11371):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-08 01:45:51.070: W/System.err(11371):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 01:45:51.070: W/System.err(11371):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-08 01:45:51.070: W/System.err(11371):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
07-08 01:45:51.070: W/System.err(11371):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
07-08 01:45:51.070: W/System.err(11371):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 01:45:51.070: W/System.err(11371): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
07-08 01:45:51.070: W/System.err(11371):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
07-08 01:45:51.070: W/System.err(11371):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
07-08 01:45:51.070: W/System.err(11371):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
07-08 01:45:51.075: W/System.err(11371):    ... 24 more
07-08 01:45:51.075: E/error occured(11371): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/hasebou.karim.simplify/cache/Details.txt: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
07-08 01:45:51.335: D/AbsListView(11371): Get MotionRecognitionManager
07-08 01:45:51.355: D/dalvikvm(11371): GC_CONCURRENT freed 165K, 9% free 12708K/13831K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 35ms
07-08 01:45:51.540: E/SpannableStringBuilder(11371): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-08 01:45:51.540: E/SpannableStringBuilder(11371): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-08 01:45:51.565: E/SpannableStringBuilder(11371): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-08 01:45:51.565: E/SpannableStringBuilder(11371): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

---

```
 File file = new File(mainAct.getCacheDir(), "Details.txt");
                try {
                    if(file.createNewFile()){   
                        Log.e("making file", " file made");
                    }
                PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(file);
                String everyThing = s.name + "\n" +s.time + "\n" + s.onoff +"\n";
                for(boolean b : s.daysofweek){
                    if(b == true){
                        everyThing += "1";
                    }
                    else{
                        everyThing += "0";
                    }
                }
                everyThing += "\n";
                for(boolean b : s.sensors){
                    if(b == true){
                        everyThing += "1";
                    }
                    else{
                        everyThing += "0";
                    }
                }
                everyThing += "\n" + "End";
                write.print(everyThing);
                write.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("error occured", e.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: btw s is a class with public variables

Comment: Where do you get the exception? Stacktrace would be very helpful.

Comment: what is the `s` variable?

Comment: public class SoundDetails {
 public boolean[] sensors ; // wifi gps 3g bluetooth airplane
 public boolean[] daysofweek ;
 public String onoff ="";
 public String name;
 public String time;
  public SoundDetails(boolean[] sensors, boolean[] daysofweek,String onoff,String name,String time){
   this.sensors = sensors;
   this.daysofweek = daysofweek;
   this.onoff = onoff;
   this.name = name;
   this.time = time;
  }
}
here is the SoundDetail which i made an instance of called s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any folder with the same name as the file you are downloading ?

You may try to clean up that before creating the File `PrintWriter` with the following:

```
new File(xxxx).delete();
```